# Slaves to the mother

Tags: riddle

Our houses empty, were on a raid
Nomadic creatures who never stayed
Predators on a smaller scale
Tiny in mass but in no way frail

Our brothers colonise in their zounds
Along the ground, under mounds
A matriarch leads us through the fray
The caverns flood with larva, no play

Racism rife in amongst the kingdoms
Pillaging, taking the enemies freedoms
No free time can distract me from finding food
We work as one for the greater good

Comment: Two poem riddles about ants in two days? Odd.

Comment: @IanMacDonald maybe it's because they are such an amazing creature!

Comment: Maybe it's a different kind of ant!

Comment: I don't think it's about ants at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the answer...

> [Slave-making Ants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave-making_ant)